# Install requests by pip, but it doesn't work

Tags: python

I have installed Homebrew which includes pip, doesn't it?
But when I type $ pip install requests, in terminal, it shows

-bash: pip: command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebrew is a Mac package manager. You can use it to install pip, among other things, but it doesn't do so until you tell it to.

Comment: I refer to this website, http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install3/osx/#install3-osx , which said "Homebrew installs pip3 for you.

pip3 is the alias for the Python 3 version of pip on systems with both the Homebrew’d Python 2 and 3 installed."

Comment: It installs pip3 *when you install Python 3* via homebrew. Did you do that? Plus, that's pip3, not pip.

Comment: I am not sure, but when I type $ python3 ,it shows Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: And what happens when you run `pip3`?

Answer (score 0):

Not as far is I know - you'd need to install python which should include pip.

Comment: I have install python 2.7.1

Comment: is /usr/local/bin in your $PATH? are you sure you can execute the formulas installed with homebrew?

Answer (score 0):

You mention trying "pip" while the documentation clearly mentions "pip3". On certain systems there's a difference.